# Update link for each table row

Tags: php, mysql

With the code i have i can succesfully read and display data from my database, 
"agencies_validation" does this. I also manage to make it so it display Update Link for each row. But the Update link doesen't work. So what i want it to do is when i click Update link it calls "agencies_admin_update.php" which is supposed to Update that row. But it doesn't work.

```
//agencies_validation

            <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>


            <?php

    include_once 'database.php';
    echo '<form action= "agencies_admin_update.php" method="get">'; 
    $valid_query = "SELECT * FROM agencies ";
    $valid_result = mysqli_query($link, $valid_query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($valid_result)) {
        echo '<tr>';

        $id = $row['id'];
        echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
        echo  "<td><a href='agencies_admin_update.php?'>UPDATE</a></td>";
        echo '<tr>';
    }
        echo '</form>';
            ?>

            </table>
```

and

```
//agencies_admin_update.php
    <?php
        include_once 'database.php';
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "UPDATE agencies SET admin=2 WHERE id = $id";
        header("Location: agencies_validation.php");


        ?>
```

Comment: because you don't send the `id` with the link: `...'agencies_admin_update.php?id=".$row['id']."'...`

Comment: i put this code: echo  "<td><a href='agencies_admin_update.php?id=".$row['id']."'>UPDATE</a></td>"; but it still doesn't work.

Comment: do you want to get hacked or does it not matter to you? you've a serious sql injection opening there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you have to add the ID to link URL:

```
...
echo  "<td><a href='agencies_admin_update.php?id=" . $id . "'>UPDATE</a></td>";
...
```

The second you must not only to generate the SQL query, but and execute it:

```
...
$query = "UPDATE agencies SET admin=2 WHERE id = $id";
mysqli_query($link, $query)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is really all code, then I think, you are just specifying your query in `agencies_admin_update.php` and not executing it.

See here:

```
$query = "UPDATE agencies SET admin=2 WHERE id = $id";
```

The `$query` variable is set, but not executed.
After specifying the variable you are redirecting the user immidiately with this code:

```
        header("Location: agencies_validation.php");
```

But I'm wondering, how this should work, because you have no `$id` specified, which you want to update in  `agencies_admin_update.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
 <td><a href='agencies_admin_update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>UPDATE</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the update query in the `agencies_admin_update.php` file and send id with the url in `agencies_validation` file

```
//agencies_validation

        <table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td>title</td>
    </tr>


        <?php

include_once 'database.php';
echo '<form action= "agencies_admin_update.php" method="get">'; 
$valid_query = "SELECT * FROM agencies ";
$valid_result = mysqli_query($link, $valid_query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($valid_result)) {
    echo '<tr>';

    $id = $row['id'];
    echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
    echo  "<td><a href='agencies_admin_update.php?id=".$id."'>UPDATE</a></td>";
    echo '<tr>';
}
    echo '</form>';
        ?>

        </table>
```

Execute query in this file

```
// agencies_validation
<?php
    include_once 'database.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE agencies SET admin=2 WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if($result) {
        // Show success message
        header("Location: agencies_validation.php");
    } else {
       // Show error message
       header("Location: agencies_validation.php");
    }

    ?>
```